# How to isolate TFS build agents to build with different versions of VS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

We have one TFS build controller with four build agents.  We also have VS 2013 on all four build agents to build our VS 2013 projects. We now need to start building new projects with VS 2015. We’ve already noticed that some of the VS 2013 projects fail to build on a TFS build agent with VS 2015 so we need to find a way to isolate the build agent with VS 2015 and only build VS 2015 based projects on a TFS build agent with VS 2015 without impacting the VS 2013 projects. How can this be done with only one TFS build controller? Do we need to create a 2nd build controller on the same TFS server to handle VS 2015 builds? I've read this can be done (more than one build controller on same TFS server) but this scenario is not supported by MS.

Comment: Did you try to use tags for build agents?

Comment: Hmm..haven't tried build agent tags. So let's say I add a tag called "VS2015" for one of the build agents that has VS2015, and then add the "VS2015" tag to the build definitions for the new projects requiring VS2015. What about the non-VS2015 projects? If the build definitions for VS2013 projects don't have the "VS2015" tag, will they not use the build agent with VS2015 and use the other build agents? That's the desired result.

Comment: I'd recommend to use also VS2013 tag; in that way you'll avoid to remember what are doing the "tagless" build definitions

Comment: Thanks! You and Daniel Mann gave some good tips on how to handle this problem via build definitions. Was hoping to avoid updating our many, many build definitions but may have to go this route to avoid setting up another build controller and build agent.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need separate controllers or agents for this. You can explicitly specify the Visual Studio version and MSbuild version by passing MSbuild arguments in your build definition.

### Visual Studio

`/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0` will force it to use VS 2013.

`/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0` will force it to use VS 2015.

### MSBuild

`/tv:12.0` will force MSBuild to use the VS 2013 version.

`/tv:14.0` will force MSBuild to use the VS 2015 version.

Comment: We would like to avoid this option if possible since we have dozens and dozens of VS2013 projects whose build definitions we would have to update just to support building a couple VS2015 projects. Eventually the VS2013 projects will probably be converted to VS2015, but that's later down the road.

Comment: You only need to do it for the VS2015 projects

Comment: We would want the VS 2013 projects to avoid using the build agent with VS 2015 altogether, so wouldn't we also need to update the VS2013 build definitions?

Comment: My point is that you can avoid having separate build agents altogether and just install 2013 and 2015 side by side. If you're using a TFS2013 build process template, everything will default to VS2013. Then you can force VS2015 with MSbuild arguments where appropriate.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but one of the issues we ran into with building a VS2013 project on a machine with VS2015 was due to .NET 4.6, which broke our build with Fakes assemblies. This is one of the reasons why we need to keep the VS2015 agent isolated from the VS2013 projects.